# Angular Component is not a known element when declared in the same module

Tags: angular

I understand that this is probably is a stupid mistake, but I've been staring at the screen for hours now and really need help.

I have **desktop.component.ts** and **header.component.ts**, both declared in **desktop.module.ts** and yet I get an error stating that:

*Error: src/app/desktop/desktop.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element.*

The desktop.component.ts is just:

```
<app-header title="Some Title"></app-header>
```

[image: Screenshot of Desktop.module.ts]

Comment: Possible stupid question, but have you made sure that `app-header` is the selector in the component file?

Comment: Same as above, more specifically does `HeaderComponent` have `selector: "app-header"` and does this have `@Input() title`

Comment: possibly a stupid suggestion, but did you restart angular server after making change in DesktopModule file?

Comment: Have you imported desktop.module.ts to app.module.ts?

Comment: @WillAlexander - yes, the selector is indeed app-header and there is an Input with correct naming :( Also I have restarted server and even cleared IDE cache, read that that might be the problem - nothing helped so far

Comment: @WaleedAhmad that's it! How could I miss this?! Thank you so much!